# Combine lapply, seq_along and ddply

Tags: r, lapply

I've been searching around this forum and trying to implement in my case what was said in previous answers from those questions. However, something in my code is missing.

I use lapply() with a function inside that runs ddply. This works nice. However, I would like to identify every result from a single data frame by reading the name of the data frame, and not [[1]], [[2]]...

For this reason, I am trying to implement the seq_along argument, but unsuccessfully. Let's see what I have:

1. I created a list to group 16 different data frames (with the same structure) in one object, called melt_noNA_noDC_regression:

   ```
   melt_noNA_noDC_regression <- 
   list(I1U_melt_noNA_noDC_regression, I1L_melt_noNA_noDC_regression,
     I1U_melt_noNA_noDC_regression, I1L_melt_noNA_noDC_regression,
     CU_melt_noNA_noDC_regression, CL_melt_noNA_noDC_regression,
     P3U_melt_noNA_noDC_regression, P3L_melt_noNA_noDC_regression,
     P4U_melt_noNA_noDC_regression, P4L_melt_noNA_noDC_regression,
     M1U_melt_noNA_noDC_regression, M1L_melt_noNA_noDC_regression, 
     M2U_melt_noNA_noDC_regression, M2L_melt_noNA_noDC_regression,
     M3U_melt_noNA_noDC_regression, M3L_melt_noNA_noDC_regression)
   ```
2. Later, I run this lapply() line successfully.

   ```
   lapply(melt_noNA_noDC_regression, function(x) ddply(x, .(Species), model_regression))
   ```
3. As I have 16 different data frames, I would like to identify them in the results of the lapply function. I have tried several combinations to include seq_along within the lapply code, as in this case:

   ```
   lapply(melt_noNA_noDC_regression, function(x) {
           ddply(x, .(Species), model_regression)      
           seq_along(x), function(i) paste(names(x)[[i]], x[[i]])
   })
   ```

However, I've been getting errors constantly, and it is a bit frustrating. It is maybe very easy to solve, but I am block.

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried using a named list in your first step? lapply keeps the names of your list elements and you can use these names later to access specific results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `eapply` (`lapply`'s lesser known sibling) or `mget` to retrieve a named list of your dataframes. Then run them through `lapply` for the `ddply` call to return the same named dataframe list with new corresponding values.

```
df_list <- eapply(.GlobalEnv, function(d) d)[c("I1U_melt_noNA_noDC_regression",
                                               "I1L_melt_noNA_noDC_regression",
                                               "I1U_melt_noNA_noDC_regression",
                                               ...)]

df_list <- mget(c("I1U_melt_noNA_noDC_regression",
                  "I1L_melt_noNA_noDC_regression",
                  "I1U_melt_noNA_noDC_regression",
                  ...))

# GENERALIZED FOR ANY DF IN GLOBAL ENV
df_list <- Filter(function(i) class(i)=="data.frame", eapply(.GlobalEnv, function(d) d))

new_list <- lapply(df_list, function(x) ddply(x, .(Species), model_regression))
```

And because `eapply` (being **e**nvironment **apply**) is part of the apply family and can iterate through objects, you can bypass `lapply`. But you must account for non-dataframes and then filter out by df names. Hence, `tryCatch` is used and `[]` indexing:

```
new_list2 <- eapply(.GlobalEnv, function(x) 
     tryCatch(ddply(x, .(Species), model_regression),
              warning = function(w) return(NA),
              error = function(e) return(NA)
             )
     )[c("I1U_melt_noNA_noDC_regression",
         "I1L_melt_noNA_noDC_regression",
         "I1U_melt_noNA_noDC_regression",
         ...)]

all.equal(new_list, new_list2)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

With all that said, ideally in your data processing you would originally use a named dataframe list and not create separate, similar structured 16 objects flooding your global environment. Therefore, consider adjusting the source of your *regression* objects, so replace the following:

```
I1U_melt_noNA_noDC_regression <- ...
```

with this:

```
df_list = list()
df_list["I1U_melt_noNA_noDC_regression"] <- ...
```